# Upgrading nextjs from 12 to 14 and receiving Boolean Literal type error on node_modules/process/browser.js when trying to access env variables

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, package.json

I am upgrading a project from nextjs 12 to nextjs 14 in order to use the app directory routing system and middleware features. Most of the upgrade has gone smoothly however I am getting this error which source back to pages or dependencies that get environment variables from the .env file

I've tried deleting packages-lock.json, node_modules and .next cache and reinstall all the packages under new node versions but with no luck.

The error happens when switching between branches with different nextjs14 versions

Error `TypeError: Property left of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["LVal"] but instead got "BooleanLiteral"`

All the dependencies have been upgraded as of January 2024.

Node versions tried (installed via fnm package manager):

- 18.17.1
- 18.18.2
- 19.9.0
- 20.9.0
- 20.11.0

Previous version of next:

- 12.2.5

Current version of next:

- 14.0.1

If anyone has run into this before any help would be appreicated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a `.babelrc` file in your project root, from a older version of NextJs before it switched to using the SWC compiler.  Unless you have a custom babel build you can remove this and it should resolve your issue.